# Symmetric $3\times 3$ Matrices - Base matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the set of all symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices. (Recall that $V$ is a subspace of $M_{3\times 3}.$)
Find a basis of $V$ , and show that it is a basis.

I'm not sure what the question means by "basis of $V$."
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps the question should have said that V is a vector space. after all, i don't think "basis of an arbitrary set" is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix can be written as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&d&e\\
d&b&f\\
e&f&c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
That can be docomposed as a sum:

$$
a\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
c\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}+
d\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
e\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
f\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It is not difficult to show that the six matrices in this decomposition  are linearly independent, so these are  a basis for the subspace of symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 0):

A basis here will be a set of matrices that are linearly independent. The number of matrices in the set is equal to the dimension of your space, which is 6.

That is, let $dim V=n$. Then any element $A$ of $V$ (i.e. any $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix) can be written as $A=a_{1}M_{1}+…+a_{n}M_{n}$ where $M_{i}$ form the basis and $a_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$ are the coefficients.