# Finding the dimension of a vector space, and determing if it is the subspace of a parent space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, problem-solving

How could one determine the dimension of a some space which is the subspace of a particular vector space (or consider it a subspace of a particular space to begin with), say for instance given some spaces such as:

$V_1$, the vector space of all $3\times3$ *diagonal* matrices.

$V_2$, the vector space of all $3\times3$ *lower triangular* matrices.

$V_3$, the subspace of $P_3$ given by $H = \{a+bx^3:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$

$V_4$, the subspace of $P_3$ given by $\{p\in P_3:p(1)=0\}$, (and how could one for instance show that $V_4$ is a subspace of $P_3$)?

**Note**: $P_n$ is the vector space composed of the $n^{th}$ degree polynomial.

Comment: You probably want to explain what $P_3$ means for completeness.

Comment: @Abstraction That is my guess too, but rather than engage in speculation, is was the safe way to encourage the user to put its the text of the post.

Comment: @rschwieb Apologies! I will define that for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Te first step is to determine if the given subset is really a vector space, this means that it have to be closed under the addition and the scalar product, and contains the zero vector and the opposite of his elements.

Than, to find his dimension, we have to find a basis for this subspace, and the number of vectors in this basis is the dimension. The way to do this is, in general, different, for different vector spaces.

As an example, for your case $V_1$, we can see that any diagonal matrix can be expressed as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&0&0\\
0&b&0\\
0&0&c
\end{bmatrix}=
a\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
+b\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
+c\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}=
ae_{11}+be_{22}+ce_{33}
$$
where the three matrices $e_{11},e_{22},e_{33}$ on LHS are linearly independent, so the dimension of $V_1$ is $3$.

Can you do something similar for the other cases?

---

Note that in the example the kay fact is that three matrices that are a basis for the space $V_1$, and, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)), the dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of a basis.

The comment of @Abstraction points out that a vector space is well defined only if we specifies not only the set of vectors (the set $V_1$ in this case) but also the field of scalars used for the scalar product. So, as an example the set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ can be seen as a vector space over the field $\mathbb{C}$, and in this case it has dimension $1$, or over the field $\mathbb{R}$, and in this case has dimension $2$ or over $\mathbb{Q}$ and in this case his dimension is uncountably infinite. Anyway the given definition of dimension is the same: **the cardinality of a basis**. And I suppose thet the OP refers to the simpler and common case of vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.

For $V_2$, as another example, we can easily see that a basis for lower triangular matrices on $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and this means that the dimension of $V_2$ is $6$

In a similar way, a basis for $V_3$ is done by the monomials $\{1\},\{x^3\}$, so the dimension of $V_3$ is $2$.

For $V_4$ note that a polynomial of $P_3$ such that $p(1)=0$ has the form: $(x-1)(ax^2+bx+c)=ax^3+b(x^2-x)+c(x-1)$ and, since $x^3,(x^2-x),(x-1)$ are linearly independent they form a basis of $V_4$ and its dimension is $3$.

Comment: Generally it's not true (dimension of set of diagonal matrices from $R^{3 \times 3}$ as vector space over field $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite). Here it seems to be the case that we talk only about $\mathbb{R}$, but it's important that vector space definition includes the field.

Comment: I agree! But in this case it seems that the OP refers to the simpler case, where the field  is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati what does `Abstraction` mean?

Also, in regards to your answer:

So, since the diagonal matrix has only nonzero entries in the diagonal entries, and zero entries are of individual dimension $0$, the sum of the dimensions of each entry is $3$? Is that the reasoning?

Comment: @Alex Remember the definition of vector space and its dimension (Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_%28vector_space%29 may serve as a reminder, see note in "Examples" block). Term "vector space" actually refers to *two* sets - set of vectors $V$ and external field, say, $F$ (in your cases, $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$). Intuitively (that's by no means a strict definitions) "dimension" is number of elements of $F$ you need to pinpoint any specific element of $V$, so this number may be different for different $F$.

Comment: @Abstraction Apologies for my ignorance, but this seems to be bordering on the scope of what is and isn't in my knowledge, I am only in an introductory linear algebra course presently.

Real vectors spaces were defined to me as having eight given conditions in its classifications, and showing a subset requires only three not necessarily inherited from the parent space.

Comment: @Alex : I've added something to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: @EmilioNovati grazie mille, Prof. Novati! I just have one further question, what if the matrices are symmetric? Are too the places where the entries are nonzero considered to add to the dimensionality of the vector? I suspect it would not, but would rather change the vector to have only some representation like $c_1(1,0,1)$, rather than $c_1(1,0,0)$ if there was no symmetric component. No?

Comment: Loock at my answer to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487294/symmetric-3-times-3-matrices-base-matrix/1487341#1487341