# Basis and Dimension of Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the set of all $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrices. $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$. Find a basis and the dimension of $S$.  I am quite confused by it. I know how to find basis and dimension but don't understand the pre-stated set.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $A$ satisfies $A^T = A$ where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$. So $S$ is the set of all 3-by-by matrices (with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$) satisfying this property. Is the question more clear now?

Comment: Hi Luke, could you help me find the basis and the dimension of S. This is a problem I just can't figure out.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487294/symmetric-3-times-3-matrices-base-matrix for more detail. If this is a homework question, you should try and provide some additional details, though.

Answer (score 0):

A symetric matrix of shape $3\times3$ is of the form :

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b &c \\ b & d & f \\ c & f & g \end{bmatrix}$$

so a basis must represent every symmetric matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 &0 \\ 1& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, $$